# How to convert date from mm/dd/YYYY to dd/mm/YYYY in R?

Tags: r, function, date

Crime analysis data in R:

Let's say I have a very large dataset with millions of columns. One of the column has Dates such as "3/28/2020" (mm/dd/YYYY) format.

For my analysis, I need a format (dd/mm/YYYY)

I have a sample code:

```
conv <- function(a)
{ 
  dd <- strsplit(a,"/")[[1]][2]
  mm <- strsplit(a,"/")[[1]][1]
  yyyy <- strsplit(a,"/")[[1]][3]
  com <- paste(dd,mm,yyyy,sep="/")
  return(com)
             }
   a <- as.character(crime.data$Arrest.Date)
   conv(a)
```

When I do this, I get converted date but only one. That is, it only outputs the date date in column. I want all the dates to convert.

Is there any way I can do that in R? or any other function in R?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use regex or string manipulation for date-time operations.

Convert to standard date class and then use `format` to get data in desired format.

```
format(as.Date('3/28/2020', '%m/%d/%Y'), '%d/%m/%Y')
#[1] "28/03/2020"
```

Comment: I'm upvoting (because it's clean), but there are *so many questions* about parsing/(re)formatting dates and timestamps. (I understand, though, it's often easier to just answer it than to find one of many dupes.)

Comment: I am sure there are many such questions but formatting date/times and regex are the two categories of question where I am very hesitant to find a dupe because usually they are too specific.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `lubridate`

```
library(lubridate)
format(mdy("3/28/2010"), "%d/%m/%Y")
```